# about html input tag

Tags: javascript, html, input

I know almost nothing about html and javascript. So pardon me if this is a silly question.

For a html input tag like this:

```
<input name="search1$btnSearch" id="search1_btnSearch" style="background-color: white;" type="submit" value="search"/>
```

What's gonna happen when this button is clicked?

I looked in all the .js files that are referenced by the page that contains this input tag, but I did not find any code that responds to it. 
So how can I locate the code that responds to this button's click event?

By the way, I think the web site that contains this input tag is built with asp.net, because the pages have a .asxp extension.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's gonna happen when this button is clicked?

Since it is a submit button, in the absence of any JS that overrides the normal functionality, it will [submit the form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13).

> I looked in all the .js files that are referenced by the page that contains this input tag, but I did not find any code that responds to it.

There might still be some.

> So how can I locate the code that responds to this button's click event?

If it exists, it will likely show up if you turn on *profiling* in your JS debugger (make sure it is configured not to reset when you leave the page (which submitting the form will do)).

Comment: when i click the button, it redirects to another page that show the search result.

Comment: That is normal for a form submission.

Comment: so the code that responds to the click event exists on the server side and there is no legal way that we can see it , correct?

Comment: Assuming no JS is involved… the click event will have the default action, which will be to submit the form, causing the browser to make an HTTP request. The code for that is built into the browser. The server will receive the request, process it and return a HTTP response. The code for *that* exists on the server. The browser will process the response and render the new page. The code for the page will be in the HTTP response. The code for processing it will be in the browser.

Answer (score 5):

This will likely submit a form to search something on the site.

Check the `form` tag in the html to see what file is referenced.

`<form action="form_action.asp">`

The `action` references the file.

Comment: <form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">, this is form that i just found in the page

Comment: So then the form is processed by `Default.aspx`.  Open it to see how the code is processed.

Answer (score 2):

It is used to submit a form created with the help of form tags and input elements.

Answer (score 1):

It submits the form it is in. This is HTML default and doesn't need Javascript.

Comment: I know it is. ;-) It is the sole purpose of `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: is there any way to find out how the server side responds to the click event?

Comment: The `<form` element in your page contains an action, which is an url to that is requested when you submit the form. The method of the form, which is typically GET or POST, determines whether the information in the form is transferred as part of the URL (GET) or in separate headers (POST).

Comment: Normally the page will refresh, but it could be that Javascript code is added to block that, and just send the information in the background. But if I see your level of experience with the concept of forms, I would read a basic tutorials on HTML forms before starting with those Javascript hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see the .js files associated with the code it is impossible to tell. But there are a few possibilities.

1. There is no JS attached and it simply submits the form to the server for processing.
2. There is JS attached to the input element itself, in which case you would look for code like `$('#search1_btnSearch').click(function(){...`
3. There is JS attached to the onsubmit event of the form itself, in which case you would just look for submit event handlers.

You can dig deeper into this code yourself by downloading the Firebug plugin for Firefox which allows you to easily browse and manipulate HTML, JS, CSS, and more.

Comment: I guess it posts back to the server, because all the referenced .js file are used for UI decoration.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably (IF THERE IS ANY javascript) the JS event is binded to "search1_btnSearch". Use ctrl + f and search for "search1_btnSearch". 
BTW: Why do you think that there is javascript involved ? what happens?
The standard behaviour without javascript is to submit the form, in which this submit button is embedded.

Comment: can not find anywhere that references the button name, i guess it just posts back to the server

Answer (score 0):

Nothing as far as I see
May be it is attached with a form that has some action defined and a method also. So that will decide about the action.